# Spring Boot. how to Pass Optional<> to an Entity Class

Tags: java, spring-boot

i am currently making a website using spring and i stumble upon this basic scenario that i don't have any idea on how to solve this specific code: Entity = Optional;

```
RoomEntity roomEntity =  roomRepository.findById(roomId);
```

ReservationResource(API request Class):

```
    public class ReservationResource {
    @Autowired
    RoomRepository roomRepository;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/{roomId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<RoomEntity> getRoomById(
    @PathVariable
    Long roomId){
        RoomEntity roomEntity =  roomRepository.findById(roomId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(roomEntity, HttpStatus.OK);}
    }}
```

RoomRepository Class:

```
public interface RoomRepository extends CrudRepository<RoomEntity, Long> {
    List<RoomEntity> findAllById(Long id);
}
```

RoomEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Room")
public class RoomEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private Integer roomNumber;

    @NotNull
    private String price;

    public RoomEntity() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused.  You get an `Optional<RoomEntity>` back with `findById`.  You get back an `Iterable<RoomEntity>` with `findAllById`.  What specifically did you want again?

Comment: im trying to solve the first line of code i posted because the error says: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional<RoomEntity> to RoomEntity"

Comment: You can't do that conversion.  You have an `Optional<RoomEntity>`, not a `RoomEntity`.  You need to get it if it exists.

Comment: Yes sir, that is why im looking for an answer. the feels of being new to spring boot. yes i have it right now.

Comment: This is more to do with Java 8's `Optional` class and is only tangentially related to Spring Boot.  I could just *say* the specific API call you'd want to use to get back the value, but the issue there is that value may be `null` which is undesirable to always return back.  There's a deeper issue at hand, which is comprehension of the `Optional` pattern, when one uses it, why it's valuable and how you deal with the possibility of the `Optional` being empty.  A bit tough to encapsulate in just *one* answer...

Comment: its weird that in the tutorial that i follow, everything runs smoothely for him. "RoomEntity roomEntity =  roomRepository.findById(roomId);" works fine.

Comment: @kurtestacion maybe he's using a previous version of spring?

Comment: Thats true sir.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

According to your error you are getting `Optional<RoomEntity>` from repository's findAll method and you are casting it to `RoomEntity`.

Instead of `RoomEntity roomEntity =  roomRepository.findById(roomId);` do this

`Optional<RoomEntity> optinalEntity =  roomRepository.findById(roomId);
 RoomEntity roomEntity = optionalEntity.get();`

Comment: Thank you! This works for me. Is there any possibility to just disable the optional part on the repo? I still don't know how it becomes optional in the first place..

Comment: @Rdev `findById(ID id)` method is from `CrudRepository<T, ID>`. They have changed return type from `T` to `Optional<T>` to avoid `NullPointerException`. I don't see any point in replacing it to return your object `T` instead of `Optional` but if you still want to do you need to override the `findById(ID id)` or you can use `JPARepository` instead of `CrudRepository` and call method `getOne(ID id)`.

Answer (score 11):

The answers lack some job to do. Before you call `get()`, you should do some checking with `isPresent()`. Like so:

```
Optional<RoomEntity> optionalEntity =  roomRepository.findById(roomId);
if (optionalEntity.isPresent()) {
    RoomEntity roomEntity = optionalEntity.get();
    ...
}
```

Read this great article about optionals: https://dzone.com/articles/using-optional-correctly-is-not-optional

Answer (score 7):

Try this, it works for me

`RoomEntity roomEntity =  roomRepository.findById(roomId).orElse(null);`

Comment: This is not correct; it defeats the very purpose of `Optional` itself. `Optional` was introduced to avoid working with `null` values. If we really want to assign a not existing value to a variable, we should use Optional.empty().

Comment: Its riscky strategy if you want to use roomEntity somewhere without try catch.
it will make the webserver return null pointer and its againts the purpose of using optional.

Answer (score 2):

**First solution**

You can implement `JpaRepository` instead of `CrudRepository` which provide a getOne method that returns an RoomEntity as you expect. (`JpaRepository`  for JPA or `MongoRepository` for MongoDB) :

```
public interface RoomRepository extends JpaRepository<RoomEntity, Long> {
    List<RoomEntity> findAllById(Long id);
}
```

and

```
RoomEntity roomEntity = roomRepository.getOne(roomId);
```

Note that an `EntityNotFoundException` will be thrown if there's no RoomEntity for this roomId.

**Second solution**

The findById method of CrudRepository returns an optional so you must deal with it properly to get an RoomEntity if there is one. For example :

```
RoomEntity roomEntity = optionalEntity.roomRepository.findById(roomId).get();
```

In this case `.get()` will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if there's no RoomEntity for this roomId.

This article may help to understand optionals : http://www.baeldung.com/java-optional

Answer (score 2):

`RoomEntity roomEntity = roomRepository.findById(id).get();`

This will solve your error!

Answer (score 0):

**The shortest way of doing this casting**

```
RoomEntity roomEntity = roomRepository.findById(roomId).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

As @kaush-athukorala said, you need just add `.get()`at the end of `RoomEntity roomEntity =  roomRepository.findById(roomId);` It works

You'll have `RoomEntity roomEntity =  roomRepository.findById(roomId).get();`

Answer (score 0):

You  can  use  one of  this ,

RoomEntity roomEntity =  roomRepository.findById(roomId).get();

OR

RoomEntity roomEntity =  roomRepository.findById(roomId).orElse(null);

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
Boolean roomEntity = roomRepository.existsById(roomId);

Check if exists then return true else false

OR

RoomEntity roomEntity = roomRepository.getById(roomId);

    if(roomEntity != null) {
    }

OR

This method is deprecated in new version. if you are using older version then it will work fine.


Optional<RoomEntity> roomEntity = roomRepository.getOne(roomId);

   if(roomEntity.isPresent()) {
   }
```